# Seeding a database with "flights"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, validation

I'm trying to seed my database and I keep getting the error "ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Arriving flight must exist". In my method to create the association in my seeds.rb file I supply the arrival_airport_id so I'm not sure what the problem is.

seeds.rb

```
Airport.delete_all
Flight.delete_all

#Airport seeds
airports = [
["Boston Logan International Airport", "BOS"],
["Gulfport", "GPT"],
["Jackson", "JAN"],
["Charleston", "CRW"]
]

airports.each do |full_name, name|
  Airport.create!( full_name: full_name, name: name )
end

  a = Airport.all[0..1]
  b = Airport.all[2..3]

  a.each_with_index do |a, index|
    a.departing_flights.create!(
      arrival_airport_id: b[index]
      )
  end
```

Airport model:

```
class Airport < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :departing_flights, class_name: "Flight", foreign_key: "departing_airport_id"
    has_many :arriving_flights, class_name: "Flight", foreign_key: "arrival_airport_id"
end
```

Flight model:

```
class Flight < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :departing_flight, class_name: "Airport", foreign_key: "departing_airport_id"
    belongs_to :arriving_flight, class_name: "Airport", foreign_key: "arrival_airport_id" 
end
```

Comment: I changed arrival_airport_id: b[index] to arrival_airport_id: b[index].id and it worked but I thought rails would know to do that already?

Comment: If you think you resolved the problem, you can answer your question and help to other people.

Comment: I was going to but I'm not sure if this was the correct fix. I figured I'd see how someone else would have gone about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common mistake and there are two fixes.

```
a.each_with_index do |a, index|
  a.departing_flights.create!(
    arrival_airport_id: b[index]  # This line is the problem
    )
end
```

You're assigning an object to an id column. You can either assign the id to the id column or the object to the object column.

```
arrival_airport_id: b[index].id
# or
arrival_airport: b[index]
```

Rails tries to help you out the best it can but you have to give it the right object types.